# Creating a post request using axios in react to send data to a Spring Boot endpoint

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, spring-boot, axios

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

export default function CreateiPhone(){
    const [iphone, setiPhone] = useState({
        id: "",
        name: "",
        model: "",
        configuration: "",
        imgUrl: "",
    });
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        setiPhone({...iphone, [e.target.name]: value });
    };
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefualt();

        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/createiPhone", {iphone})
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.status, response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    };
```

Below is the form that should send that data on submit to my endpoint.

```
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
                <label htmlFor="Id">ID:</label>
                <input
                    id="Id"
                    type = "text"
                    name = "id"
                    value={iphone.id}
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="Name">
                    Name:
                </label>
                <input
                    id="Name"
                    type = "text"
                    name = "name"
                    value={iphone.name}
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="Model">
                    Model:
                </label>
                <input
                    id="Model"
                    type="text"
                    name="model"
                    value={iphone.model}
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="Configuration">
                    Configuration:
                </label>
                <input
                    id="Configuration"
                    type="text"
                    name="configuration"
                    value={iphone.configuration}
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="ImgUrl">
                    imgUrl:
                </label>
                <input
                    id="ImgUrl"
                    type="text"
                    name="imgUrl"
                    value={iphone.imgUrl}
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
                <button
                type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Below is the server-side code

```
    @PostMapping("/api/createiPhone")
    public iPhoneItem create(@RequestBody iPhoneItem iphoneitem) {
        return iphoneservice.createiPhone(iphoneitem);
    }
```

Here is the iPhoneItem class

```
package com.iPhoneRepair.iPhoneRepairApp.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class iPhoneItem {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String model;
    private String configuration;
    private String imgUrl;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void setConfiguration(String configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

}
```

I know I can send data to my database through the Spring Boot endpoint I created, however I can't seem to send my form data to that endpoint or at least it does not show up in my database. When I submit the form the page refreshes and nothing is outputted to the console.

Comment: It might your `handleSubmit` is not bind with your form and add the form element in your question

Comment: @YuvarajM I added the form, thanks.

Comment: Just added the server-side code to the post.

Comment: There is an prop called `noValidate` on the form that you are not using. Maybe your form is trying to validate and it can't because something is wrong. Add the prop to your `<form>` element and see if it allows the POST http request

Comment: Add it where? Sorry I am not sure.

Comment: `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>`

Comment: @skellertor there is no validation attributes within the form. `novalidate` is extremely unlikely to make any difference here

Comment: @Phil Where would I put the iPhoneItem class?

Comment: Added the iPhoneItem class.

Comment: @Phil is correct. Your payload is wrong

Comment: So the change I would make is removing the curly brackets around the iphone in the axios post request? I did that and it still is not working? Am I missing something?

Comment: Change this `<form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>` into `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`

Comment: @YuvarajM that is functionally identical

Comment: e.preventDefault() is spelled incorrectly. That is why your page is refreshing and not working. you have e.preventDefualt()

Comment: @skellertor super

Comment: I just changed that however, the data is still not being sent to my database.

Comment: So what happens now? Does the `catch` block handle the error? If so, what does it log? FYI this would be a better log message... `console.error("Error", error.response?.status, error.response?.data)`

Comment: Honestly this is my first time doing all this so I was just trying to get anything to the console at that point. Thanks for the additional input though, will add right away.

Answer (score 1):

Given your controller method binds the request body to your `iPhoneItem` class...

```java
@RequestBody iPhoneItem iphoneitem
```

and your model looks like this

```java
public class iPhoneItem { //  FYI this is not a good Java class name
  private String id;
  private Stringb name;
  // ...
```

When you post data like this

> ```js
> axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/createiPhone", {iphone})
> ```

`{iphone}` is the same as `{ iphone: iphone }` (see [Object initializer - Property definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions)) so you're actually sending a request body like this where everything is nested under an `"iphone"` property

```json
{
  "iphone": {
    "id": "...",
    "name": "...",
    ...
  }
}
```

which doesn't match your `@RequestBody` model.

```js
const iphone = {
  id: "1",
  name: "iPhone 15",
  model: "iPhone 15",
  configuration: "all space taken by OS",
  imgUrl: "https://example.com/iphone15.jpg",
};

console.log("compare");
console.log(iphone);
console.log({iphone});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Simply remove the `{...}` to send the data without nesting

```js
//                                                    no braces
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/createiPhone", iphone)
```

---

I highly recommend you adopt Typescript in your client-side code. Then you would easily catch typos like `e.preventDefualt()`

```ts
const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement> = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); //  no chance of a typo now
  // ...
```

Comment: This answer is a good answer, although it didn't fix the OP's issue. @Phil is correct that the payload is also an issue and will crop up after the OP fixes their current issue

Answer (score 1):

Change `e.preventDefualt()` to `e.preventDefault()`. What is happening is the default submit behavior is to refresh the page. Since it is not being called correctly, the default behavior is happening and the page is refreshing without your POST request being fired.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I changed the spelling error but then got a CORS error. However all I needed to do was add the @CrossOrigins annotation to to the endpoint.

Comment: So it sounds like there are a number of issues. With all three answers combined it sounds like you now are in a working state. Good luck my friend! And don't forget to upvote @Phils answer. He fixed a future issue you were going to certainly run into